# assignment error with Mat OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working with OpenCV and C++ for a project and I found the following problem: after initializing a mat with the following statement

```
Mat or_mat=Mat(img->height,img->width,CV_32FC1);
```

check the following value

```
or_mat.at <float> (i, j) = atan (fy / fx) / 2 +1.5707963;
```

After completing returning the mat for the output of the function but when I go to read there are many values ​​that do not correspond to the output. Precise in incorrect values ​​for the I-4.31602e +008 is inserted and if I make a `cout` the value of the expression is correct. What could be the error??

relevant Code:

```
Mat or_mat=Mat(img->height,img->width,CV_32FC1);

to angle
if(fx > 0){   
    or_mat.at<float>(i,j) = atan(fy/fx)/2+1.5707963;
}
else if(fx<0 && fy >0){   
    or_mat.at<float>(i,j) = atan(fy/fx)/2+3.1415926;
}
else if(fx<0 && fy <0){   
    or_mat.at<float>(i,j) = atan(fy/fx)/2;
}
else if(fy!=0 && fx==0){   
    or_mat.at<float>(i,j) = 1.5707963;
}
```

I have to calculate the local orientation of the fingerprint image, the following code I have omitted several statements and calculations that do not have errors.

Comment: First, specify the channel: `CV_32FC1` or `CV_32FC3`. And post the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would triple check that you are indexing correctly. The following code shows my initialising a matrix full of zeros, and then filling it with some float using at `.at` operator. It compiles and runs nicely:

```
int main()
{

    int height = 10;
    int width = 3;

    // Initialise or_mat to with every element set to zero
    cv::Mat or_mat = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_32FC1);
    std::cout << "Original or_mat:\n" << or_mat << std::endl;

    // Loop through and set each element equal to some float
    float value = 10.254;
    for (int i = 0; i < or_mat.rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < or_mat.cols; ++j)
        {
            or_mat.at<float>(i,j) = value;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Final or_mat:\n" << or_mat << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried using only Mat initializing the structure with the following statement:
Mat or_mat = Mat(img-> height, img-> width, CV_32F);
and assign the value as above. The error persists.

Comment: You seem to be mixing between using `CvMat *` and `cv::Mat` - these are different structures and you should probably choose one or the other.

Comment: Note that in [the latest documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#cvmat) `CvMat` is considered obsolete...

Comment: I chose to use cv:: Mat and the code you see. The problem is not when the value is calculated and assigned to the position (i, j ).... causes some problems and does not assign the correct value.

Comment: i have correct the post with new code. i use only cv::mat and not Cvmat*

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example showing a working use of the `.at` operator

Comment: Make good use of the operator. At, but I solved initializing to zero. In my results I can accept zero and most likely if the cv:: Mat is not initialized will contain items that are not in those values​​.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad this helped you. Note that for initialising matrices OpenCV also has the functions `cv::Mat::ones` and also `cv::Mat::eye` with similar arguments which initialise your matrix to ones, or the identity matrix as required by the application.